# Jetty WebSocketServlet NPE

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I try to use jetty web socket and have some troubles, may be you know how to fix them.

There is SocketServlet (from example):

```
public class SocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
      factory.register(MyEchoSocket.class);
  }
}
```

And EchoSocket

```
@WebSocket
public class MyEchoSocket {

   @OnWebSocketConnect
   public void onConnect(Session session){
       System.out.println("Connect");
   }
}
```

web.xml (part)

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SocketServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.servlets.SocketServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SocketServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And when i build and run it with maven i have NPE:

2013-07-18 23:20:29.488:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/hello
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.upgrade(WebSocketServerFactory.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketServerFactory.acceptWebSocket(WebSocketServerFactory.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServlet.service(WebSocketServlet.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

I use
jetty version 9.0.4.v20130625
jettyPlugin.version 8.1.10.v20130312
java 1.7.25

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue, that just caused by a static method in HttpConnection, which would generate a threadLocale.  and it used initValue() method, but I cannot found why this method would hardly return null in a short time.
We can find all of these is happening under tomcat.

When I change to run it in jetty, it goes well.

So we can realize that the websocket module of jetty is not independent, but based on jetty server. We'd better implement a websocketServlet.